# Methods called after new state is set inside a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to understand the re-render lifecycle of React Components. Once `setState` is called, it re-renders the component. But what all life cycle methods will be called (in correct order) when re--rendering begins? 
Below diagram from Dan Abramov is helpful, but it doesn't throw much light on the re-rendering phase of a React component.

[image: React LifeCycle Methods]

If `getDerivedStateFromProps` returns a new state (thus 'setting' a new state like `setState`), does it cause re-rendering? If yes, won't the re-rendering cause `getDerivedStateFromProps` to be called again, causing an infinite loop (assuming there is no condition for props checking inside `getDerivedStateFromProps`)?

Comment: The diagram is quite clear: when new props come in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, if defined, will be called. The state returned doesn't trigger a re-render: render hasn't happened yet. The state will then be fed through `shouldComponentUpdate` (again, if defined). *Then* render happens. Calling `setState` jumps straight to `shouldComponentUpdate`, there's no change in props.

Comment: @JaredSmith Actually I noticed that image could be misleading! `getDerivedStateFromProps` gets called even if you call `setState`.

Comment: @JaredSmith Aha, OP is using some old image, here the issue is corrected: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ (OPs image is for version 16.3)

Comment: @JaredSmith : It is not immediately obvious that `getDerivedStateFromProps` will not cause re-rendering, given the history of React. `componentWillUpdate` too is (or was) called before `render`,  and using `setState` inside it causes infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Once setState is called, it re-renders the component. But what all
>   life cycle methods will be called (in correct order) when
>   re--rendering begins?

Once `setState` is called, that "period" is called **Updating** on the screen shot you gave (but updating can also happen for new props as shown on the image), hence you should refer to that part of the image - it also shows which method comes after which.

> If yes, won't the re-rendering cause getDerivedStateFromProps to be
>   called again, causing an infinite loop (assuming there is no condition
>   for props checking inside getDerivedStateFromProps)?

No, it will not cause an infinite loop. Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-frost-niw6b) to demo that.
However, it seems in later versions of react (http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/), GDSFP is called even after `setState`, so you may want to double think if unconditionally returning new state from it is what you want.

Comment: It's a bit confusing that `getDerivedStateFromProps` 'sets' a new state like `setState` but yet doesn't cause re-rendering. In React world, we have always come to believe that setting new state should re-render the component..

Comment: @maverick yep, but that is how it works. I will also update answer because it seems on the new react GDSFP is called even after you call setState

Comment: This behaviour is even more confusing! `getDerivedStateFromProps` not causing a re-render and overwriting state set by `setState` is kind of antipattern for React.. Wonder if React team gave this a very good thought!

Comment: it will not overwrite though rather merge with old state, but yeah, these lifecycles can be tricky, that's why they say probably not to use GDSFP often.

Answer (score 1):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` does not inherently set a new state like `setState`, and so, it does not cause re-rendering *per se*.

Quoting [dave-ceddia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465887/dave-ceddia) in his book "Pure React":

> **static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)**: This is an opportunity to change the state based on the value of props, which can be useful for initialization. It’s not used very frequently. Don’t call setState here, but instead, return an object that represents the new state. This method must not have side effects. Also, don’t forget the static keyword before this method or it won’t work. Since this method is static, you can’t access the this object.

Comment: "`getDerivedStateFromProps` does not inherently set a new state like `setState`" - Well a new state *is* set when a new state object is returned!